# how to set input as public constanta

Tags: java

hi all i have code main and tictactoe class

here my example
of main class. in this code i input something like string number

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
         SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                 System.out.println("Enter number of ROW Column Do you want to use");
                 String input = scanner.next();
                 Integer Input = Integer.parseInt(input);
                new TTTGraphics2P(Input); // Let the constructor do the job
             }
          });
```

and this is for my class of tictactoe program. if i run this code i only have 3x3 tictactoe program, so i want to modify one of code using my input so my tictactoe will be Input x input

```
public class TTTGraphics2P extends JFrame {
   // Named-constants for the game board
   public static final int ROWS = 3;  // ROWS by COLS cells
   public static final int COLS = 3;
 
   // Named-constants of the various dimensions used for graphics drawing
   public static final int CELL_SIZE = 100; // cell width and height (square)
   public static final int CANVAS_WIDTH = CELL_SIZE * COLS;  // the drawing canvas
   public static final int CANVAS_HEIGHT = CELL_SIZE * ROWS;
   public static final int GRID_WIDTH = 8;                   // Grid-line's width
   public static final int GRID_WIDHT_HALF = GRID_WIDTH / 2; // Grid-line's half-width
   // Symbols (cross/nought) are displayed inside a cell, with padding from border
   public static final int CELL_PADDING = CELL_SIZE / 6;
   public static final int SYMBOL_SIZE = CELL_SIZE - CELL_PADDING * 2; // width/height
   public static final int SYMBOL_STROKE_WIDTH = 8; // pen's stroke width
 
   // Use an enumeration (inner class) to represent the various states of the game
   public enum GameState {
      PLAYING, DRAW, CROSS_WON, NOUGHT_WON
   }
   private GameState currentState;  // the current game state
 
   // Use an enumeration (inner class) to represent the seeds and cell contents
   public enum Seed {
      EMPTY, CROSS, NOUGHT
   }
   private Seed currentPlayer;  // the current player
 
   private Seed[][] board   ; // Game board of ROWS-by-COLS cells
   private JPanel canvas; // Drawing canvas (JPanel) for the game board
   private JLabel statusBar;  // Status Bar
 
   /** Constructor to setup the game and the GUI components 
 * @param input */
   public TTTGraphics2P(Integer input) {
      canvas = new DrawCanvas();  // Construct a drawing canvas (a JPanel)
      canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT));
 
      // The canvas (JPanel) fires a MouseEvent upon mouse-click
      canvas.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {  // mouse-clicked handler
            int mouseX = e.getX();
            int mouseY = e.getY();
            // Get the row and column clicked
            int rowSelected = mouseY / CELL_SIZE;
            int colSelected = mouseX / CELL_SIZE;
 
            if (currentState == GameState.PLAYING) {
               if (rowSelected >= 0 && rowSelected < ROWS && colSelected >= 0
                     && colSelected < COLS && board[rowSelected][colSelected] == Seed.EMPTY) {
                  board[rowSelected][colSelected] = currentPlayer; // Make a move
                  updateGame(currentPlayer, rowSelected, colSelected); // update state
                  // Switch player
                  currentPlayer = (currentPlayer == Seed.CROSS) ? Seed.NOUGHT : Seed.CROSS;
               }
            } else {       // game over
               initGame(); // restart the game
            }
            // Refresh the drawing canvas
            repaint();  // Call-back paintComponent().
         }
      });
```

my question is i want to change this field

```
public static final int ROWS = 3;  // ROWS by COLS cells
       public static final int COLS = 3;
```

become

public static final int ROWS = Input;  // ROWS by COLS cells
public static final int COLS = Input;

how to build it ?

thank you all

Comment: A `static final` like this is basically a compile time constant. First, you must make it non-final to be able to assign to it. Then it's a good idea to make it non-static, as static non-final fields are global state which is to be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Just use constructor to set `rows` and `cols`:

```
public void run() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Total rows: ");
    int rows = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Total columns: ");
    int cols = scanner.nextInt();
    new TTTGraphics2P(rows, cols);
}

public class TTTGraphics2P extends JFrame {
    private final int rows;
    private final int cols;
    
    public TTTGraphics2P(int rows, int cols) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you assign same value to final variable you can't change it. And it should be a non-static. If we static a final variable we can't assign a value in constructor. And don't forget to declare final variable without value.
Declare final variables without value.

```
public final int ROWS;
 public final int COLS;
```

Refer this sample program to find a solution for your problem.

```
public class Solution {

    public final int ROWS;
    public final int COLS;

    public Solution(int input) {
        ROWS=input;
        COLS=input;
        System.out.println(ROWS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        int input=scanner.nextInt();
        Solution s=new Solution(input);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have declared the **ROWS** and **COLS** variables as **static** they will be initialized when class is loaded. Since they are **final**, once set the value cannot be changed.

To achieve your requirement you can modify the **TTTGraphics2P** class as below to read the input and set to the variables at class loading.

```
public class TTTGraphics2P extends JFrame {
    // Named-constants for the game board
    public static final int ROWS = getInput();  // ROWS by COLS cells
    public static final int COLS = getInput();
    ...
    // Read standard input from the user
    public static int getInput() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of ROW Column Do you want to use");
        String input = scanner.next();
        return Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: This works but is a terrible idea. Initiating user interactions during class initialization is prone to cause problem and is hard to control. A better approach is to not make them `static final` and make them instance variables instead.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes 100% agree. That would be the ideal way.